# What type of triangle satisfies: $\cot \biggl( \frac{A}{2} \biggr) = \frac{b+c}{a} $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

If in a $\displaystyle\bigtriangleup$ ABC, $\displaystyle\cot \biggl( \frac{A}{2} \biggr) = \frac{b+c}{a} $, then $\displaystyle\bigtriangleup$ ABC is of which [type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#By_relative_lengths_of_sides) ?

Comment: This is tough. I got as far as establishing the relation $a(b+c)=bc(1+\cos\;A)\tan\;A$, but can't figure out the required inequalities.

Comment: @J.M: In my module they have explained it to be as right-angled triangle, but as of now I am yet to understand that explanation.

Comment: @J.M.: unfold one side (say, "b") onto the other to get a triangle with sides (a) and (b+c) and an angle (A/2). If the ratio of sides is the same as for a right triangle, that is that.

Comment: I got the idea after seeing the excellent answers already given (and I've voted all of them up), but thanks for that, @T. :) (I said inequality in that first comment since I was hoping to turn the original relation into something that looked like the law of cosines, but got mired in the algebra)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So by *Law of Sines* we have $$ \frac{a}{\sin{A}} = \frac{b}{\sin{B}} = \frac{c}{\sin{C}} =k (\text{say})$$

From this your equation becomes, $$\frac{\cos\frac{A}{2}}{\sin\frac{A}{2}} = \frac{k(\sin{B} + \sin{C})}{k \sin{A}} = \frac{\sin{B}+\sin{C}}{\sin{A}} = \frac{\cos\frac{A}{2} \cos\frac{B-C}{2}}{\sin\frac{A}{2} \cos\frac{A}{2}}$$ From this you get $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \Bigl(\frac{B+C}{2}\Bigr)= \pm \frac{B-C}{2}$$ and you can do it then.

This gives $B=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $C =\frac{\pi}{2}$, which means the triangle is *right-angled*. Hurray!

**NOTE:** The keen idea when you see problems of this type is to use the *Sine rule*. Do you think that this problem would have been difficult, if you had applied the sine rule as i did in the first step. Very often in *Mathematics* starting the solution is the difficult part. Once you figure that out, then the solutions simply flows.

Comment: @Chandru: You can't conclude that *$B$* is definitively the right angle when there's nothing in the problem that distinguishes $B$ from $C$ (or $b$ from $c$). You should point out any extra facts you're assuming (say, that $B \ge C$), and be clear when this fact comes into play. (Or, leave an appropriate sign ambiguity in your equations and  conclude that "*either* $B$ *or* $C$ is $\pi/2$".) Nevertheless, I like this approach; it's more trig than algebra, which always seems more satisfying to me. +1.

Comment: your first equation .. is it Napier's analogy or sine rule ? –However,+1 and accepted since very precise explanation and a good tip in the end :)

Comment: @Debajan: I learn't this in high school as *Napier's Analogy*.

Comment: @Day Late Don: Fixed.

Comment: @Moron: Help ke liye shukriya.

Comment: @Chandru1:Law_of_sines :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines ,which can  be used to prove Napier's analogy:http://www.tutorvista.com/content/math/trigonometry/trigonometry-math/napiers-analogy.php

Comment: @Debanjan: Ok edited.

Answer (score 3):

The cosine formula states

$$a^2 = b^2+ c^2 – 2bc \cos A$$

and since

$$\cos A = \frac{ \cot^2 (A/2) – 1}{ \cot^2(A/2)+1}$$

we have

$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 -2bc \frac{ (b+c)^2 – a^2}{(b+c)^2 + a^2},$$

which reduces to $a^4 = (b^2 – c^2)^2.$

And so taking the square root $a^2 =b^2 – c ^2,$ where $b$ is the larger side.

Hence $b^2 = c^2+a^2$ and so we have a right-angled triangle.

And so it's the angle opposite the larger of $b$ and $c$ which is the right-angle.

Answer (score 3):

OK, first rewrite it as

$$ \cos(A/2) = \frac{b+c}{a} \sin(A/2) $$

Multiply both sides by $2 \cos(A/2)$

$$ 2 \cos^2(A/2) = \frac{b+c}{a} \sin(A) $$

Now use the rule $a/\sin(A)=b/\sin(B)=c/\sin(C)$ to transform this to:

$$ 2 \cos^2(A/2) = \sin(B)+\sin(C) $$

Using Simpson's rule on the second hand of the equation to sum the sines gives:

$$ 2 \cos^2(A/2) = 2\sin((B+C)/2)\cos((B-C)/2) $$

Since in a triangle $A+B+C=\pi$ we have $ 2\sin((B+C)/2) = 2\sin((\pi-A)/2) = 2\cos(A/2) $ and thus

$$ \cos(A/2) = \cos((B-C)/2) $$

Or $A+C=B$ (If $B>C$). Combining this with $A+B+C=\pi$ this gives $B=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Begin with the Law of Cosines to compute $\cot^2\frac{A}{2}$ in terms of the lengths of the sides of the triangle:

$$\cos{A} = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
$$\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}=\frac{1+\cos{A}}{2}=\frac{2bc+b^2+c^2-a^2}{4bc} = \frac{(b+c)^2-a^2}{4bc} \\
\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}=\frac{1-\cos{A}}{2}=\frac{2bc-(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{4bc} = \frac{a^2-(b-c)^2}{4bc}
\end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cot^2\frac{A}{2}=\frac{\cos^2{\frac{A}{2}}}{\sin^2{\frac{A}{2}}}=\frac{(b+c)^2-a^2}{a^2-(b-c)^2}$$

Now, work in the condition from the problem, and let Algebra bring you home ...

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2} &=& \frac{(b+c)^2-a^2}{a^2-(b-c)^2} \\
(b+c)^2\left(a^2-(b-c)^2\right)&=& a^2\left((b+c)^2-a^2\right) \\
a^2(b+c)^2-(b+c)^2(b-c)^2 &=& a^2 (b+c)^2-a^4 \\
a^4-(b+c)^2(b-c)^2 &=& 0 \\
a^4-(b^2-c^2)^2 &=& 0 \\
\left(a^2+(b^2-c^2)\right)\left(a^2-(b^2-c^2)\right) &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
$$\Rightarrow \hspace{0.25in} a^2+b^2=c^2 \hspace{0.25in}\text{or}\hspace{0.25in} a^2+c^2=b^2$$

Nice little problem. I suspect there's a more-direct path to the solution, though. (**Edit** I see a couple such paths had been posted when I was working on my answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a geometry proof for this and thought it was worth sharing it here.

I am unable to draw the figure. I would appreciate if some one could take the effort to draw the picture or let me know what is the easiest way to draw such pictures.

Consider the triangle $ABC$. Let the angle bisector of $A$ meet $BC$ at $D$.

By angle bisector theorem, we get

$\frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{DC}{DB}$. Hence, we get $\frac{b}{c} = \frac{DC}{DB}$.

Add one to both sides, we get

$\frac{b+c}{c} = \frac{DC+DB}{DB} = \frac{a}{DB}$.

Rearranging we get $\frac{c}{DB} = \frac{b+c}{a} = \cot(\frac{A}{2})$.

A similar argument (or using the fact that $\frac{c}{DB} = \frac{b}{DC}$) yields, $\frac{b}{DC} = \frac{b+c}{a} = \cot(\frac{A}{2})$.

Now, we are almost done. (Note that if $\angle{B} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\angle{C} = \frac{\pi}{2}$, the above is true.) However, we still need to prove that for no other possibility this is satisfied.

To prove the above. Draw a perpendicular to $AB$ at $B$ and similarly draw a perpendicular to $AC$ at $C$. Let these two will intersect $AD$ at $D'$ and $D''$. Now note that $BD' = BD$ since $\frac{BD}{AB} = \cot(\frac{A}{2}) = \frac{BD'}{AB}$ (Since $D'BA$ is a right angled triangle). Similarly $CD'' = CD$.

But this is not possible unless $D' = D$ or $D'' = D$, which implies $\angle{B} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\angle{C} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Again, I would appreciate if some one could take the effort to draw the picture or let me know what is the easiest way to draw such pictures. The argument I hope however gives you the idea behind the method.